# How to use package adespatial as same as sPCA package in ade4

Tags: r

I used the package adegenet with the function sPCA to understand if there are geographical patterns in my genetic data.

```
vcf<- read.table("AMZ.012") #samples per line
vcf_m<-as.matrix(vcf)

# Add coordinates of samples
xy <-read.table("CoordAMZ_m.csv", sep=",") #geo coordinates for each sample
```

The matrix "vcf" have 0 and 1 (1 means that the information is there and 0 means no information) in each line is a different sample, as the following example:

```
0 1 0 1
1 1 0 1
1 1 0 0
```

I ran sPCA using adegenet package in R, following the example:

```
mySpca <- spca(vcf_m, xy, ask=FALSE, type=5, scannf=FALSE)
```

The result was:

```
This function is now deprecated. Please use the 'multispati' function in the 'adespatial' package.
```

I tried to use this new function but I don't have any idea how could I use as the same as implemented in sPCA and get similar results. I am expecting something like in this pdf (http://adegenet.r-forge.r-project.org/files/tutorial-spca.pdf), page 7.

I would be very happy if someone could help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are still interested but it is very simple. First have a look at the `args(multispati)` to see what is required.

The first argument required is a multi-variate ordination analysis using `dudi` in the `ade4` package.

I created a `dudi.pca`.

Then a `listw` is required.

This is simply a weighted connection network similar to what you use in sPCA but in a different format.

You can use `chooseCN` just like in your sPCA.

Then convert your `myCN` to a `listw` using the `nb2listw` function.

Hope this helps!

Cheers,
Kat